# How to mix serializers

Tags: python, django, json, serialization

I need to json serialize loads of data in django, and I need to use both `django.utils.simplejson` and `django.core.serializers`. The problem is that I can't mix them. I need something like this:

```
simplejson.dumps({
    'money': money.quantity,
    'items_left': item.quantity
    'transport': serializers.serialize([transport])
})
```

While this may work, there still are some problems with it:

1. I need to use `[transport]` to serialize just one value. I still can't figure out why the hell couldn't they add support for serializing a single model
2. `response.transport` will be a *string* that would need another json decode

*Also, if it helps, I'm using the wadofstuff json serialization module.*

How can I make this kind of serialization less hackish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.values()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-fields) in your query in order to generate a dict instead of a model instance, then just nest that dictionary in the outer dictionary.

Comment: While this would be a great thing that would entirely solve my problem, I don't have a `QuerySet`, I just have a single model instance. Can I make a QuerySet with just that model without querying the db again?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The other way around this would be to build a dict with the members you care about: `dict((field, getattr(model, field)) for field in (field1, field2, ...))`

Comment: That would be worse, because I don't have a stable spec (i.e. there is no spec), and things change very often

Comment: You can get the fields on the model by poking around in `._meta`. I can't remember the exact place, but it should be fairly self-evident.

Comment: That's perfect! The function is `instance._meta.get_all_field_names()`. Thanks! (also, please edit your answer in case other people need this)